# Close Bootstrap modal from inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, parent-child

Page which opens Twitter Bootstrap Modal with iframe inside:

```
<div id="iframeModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe src="iframe-modal.html"></iframe> 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am looking for a way to close this modal from inside the iframe.
Ex. clicking a link inside the `iframe-modal.html` to close the modal.
What I have tried, but non successful:

```
$('#iframeModal', window.parent.document).modal('hide');
$('#iframeModal', top.document).modal('hide');
$('#iframeModal').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can always create a globally accessible function which closes the Bootstrap modal window.

eg.

```
window.closeModal = function(){
    $('#iframeModal').modal('hide');
};
```

Then from the iframe, call it using:

```
window.parent.closeModal();
```

Comment: Another solution would be to use a [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) from the iframe to notify the parent window to hide the modal (this would work even if the iframe has a different domain).

Comment: since bootstrap 3 only allows one modal to be open at any given time you can make this more universal by using the class name instead of the ID attribute:
window.closeModal = function(){
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
};

Comment: This solved my problem after 2 days of trying things.  I wish I could give you more than 1 up vote!

Answer (score 16):

The issue is that jQuery events are being registered with the individual page's instance of jQuery.  So, `$('#iframeModal', window.parent.document).modal('hide');` is actually going to trigger the hide event in the iframe, not the parent document.

This should work: `parent.$('#iframeModal').modal('hide');`

This will use the parent's instance of jQuery to find the item (so no context is needed), and it will then fire the event correctly in the parent.

Comment: Helped me. This should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

One more solution in case you don't know `id` of modal which use `iframe` :

Add function *CloseModal*

```
function CloseModal(frameElement) {
     if (frameElement) {
        var dialog = $(frameElement).closest(".modal");
        if (dialog.length > 0) {
            dialog.modal("hide");
        }
     }
}
```

where `frameElement` is *reference to `iframe` element container.*

And this parameter can be passed from `iframe` like so:

```
window.parent.CloseModal(window.frameElement);
```

More about `window.frameElement` you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement)

Comment: Thank you for an elegant and yet the most generic solution that can be implemented across the application without having to rewrite the same / similar code each time - for this particular problem! This answer should really garner more upvotes... :)

Comment: Underrated  - DOPE

Answer (score 2):

You can also trigger the click the close button:

```
$('#iframeModal button.mce-close', parent.document).trigger('click');
```